# What is the time complexity of this generation algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, numbers, time-complexity, big-o

I have an number generation algo and i want to know what is its time complexity?

it generates all combinations up to length n.

below is the code snipet

```
void generate_N_Numbers(int n){
    int len = 0;
    int alphaLen = 2;
    int  *letters  = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    uint64_t outerLoopCounter = 0,innerLoopCounter1 = 0,innerLoopCounter2 = 0,
    innerLoopCounter3 = 0,innerLoopCounter4 = 0,totalLoopCounter = 0;   


    for (len=1; len<=n; len++)
    {
        outerLoopCounter++;
        int i;
        int stride = len+1;
        int bufLen = stride * alphaLen * alphaLen;

            if (len == 1) 
            continue;

        for (i=len-2; i<bufLen; i+=stride)
            innerLoopCounter1++;


        if (len == 2)
            continue;

        for (i = 0; i < len;i++){
        letters[i] = 0; 
        innerLoopCounter2++;
        }

    i = len-3;
    do {
        int  j;
        innerLoopCounter3++;

        letters[i]++;


        if (letters[i] >= alphaLen)
        letters[i] = 0;

        for (j=i;j<bufLen;j+=stride){
        innerLoopCounter4++;
        }

        if (letters[i] != 0) {
        i = len - 3;
        continue;
        }

        i--;

        if (i < 0)
        break;

    } while(1);

    }

}
```

Here is the link to this code .
https://ideone.com/HxzDGv

and here is the link to result of algorithm for inputs 1 to 30.
https://pastebin.com/LwavAff1

I am guessing its complexity is **O(n2)** but still i am not sure about this .
and this loop generates number faster than loop which has time complexity of O(n) somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct in assuming that the running time will be O(n^2). The most costly portions of your code to consider are those within two loops; all other sections are insignificant, and take O(1) time.

Your outer `for` loop will run n times, and each of the inner `for` loops will run O(n) times.

Your `do-while` loop will execute less than n times, and the `for` loop inside of it will execute at most n times.

Note that all operations within the innermost `for` loops are O(1).

To summarize this information, n*(n*1+n*1) + n*n*1 operations are required, which is O(n^2)

Note: your code is very confusing, and I made no attempt to follow the logic behind what you are doing; I just wanted to demonstrate basic complexity analysis. I would recommend taking a look at `std::next_permutation`.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, but I don’t understand that this algo still generated number faster that simple loop from i to n which has O(n) time complexity .

Comment: the Big-O-notation means -- simply put -- the function is approximately, for big enough numbers, like the argument of the O. So, `n^2 - n + 30` is O(n^2), while `1000n + 1235` is O(n). But for some small `n` the value of that O(n)-function is way bigger than that of O(n^2).